# Como consigo disparar o onclick clique nessa função com firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Preciso disparar a verificação no DB por um input. Alguém consegue me ajudar? 
Vi algumas duvidas parecidas aqui mas não consegui resolver.

```js
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBd-oV4iz3VnEL41DnNQrXcaQAKT4hPRU0",
    authDomain: "suvs-e02e4.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://suvs-e02e4.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "suvs-e02e4",
    storageBucket: "suvs-e02e4.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "156256669497",
    appId: "1:156256669497:web:a618f3f479291792e1a2e8"
};
  
document.getElementById('disp').onclick = () => {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  let SSO = document.getElementById('inputSso').value
  let db = firebase.firestore();
  let docRef = db.collection("SSOs").doc("NvZDEAmhG2Usyu2UW4Om")

  docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    let SSOs = doc.data().Ssos;
    let Arsso = SSOs;
    Arsso.includes(SSO) ? alert ("TEM") : alert("não tem")
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
  <label for="inputPassword2" class="sr-only"></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSso" placeholder="SSO">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" id="disp">Checar</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente só é necessário colocar o `initializeApp` do firebase FORA do onclick. Como você não incluiu mensagens de erro ou mais informações, presumo que o resto esteja correto e o firebase tenha sido adicionado à sua página. Segue código com as alterações (e funcionando).

```js
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBd-oV4iz3VnEL41DnNQrXcaQAKT4hPRU0",
    authDomain: "suvs-e02e4.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://suvs-e02e4.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "suvs-e02e4",
    storageBucket: "suvs-e02e4.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "156256669497",
    appId: "1:156256669497:web:a618f3f479291792e1a2e8"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

document.getElementById('disp').onclick = () => {
  let SSO = document.getElementById('inputSso').value
  
  let db = firebase.firestore();
  let docRef = db.collection("SSOs").doc("NvZDEAmhG2Usyu2UW4Om");
  docRef.get()
    .then((doc) =>
    {
      let SSOs = doc.data().Ssos;
      document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = SSOs;
      SSOs.includes(SSO) ? alert("TEM") : alert("não tem");
    });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
  <label for="inputPassword2" class="sr-only"></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSso" placeholder="SSO">
</div>
 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" id="disp">Checar</button>

<div id="resultado"></div>
```

PS: note que a linha `let Arsso =SSOs;` foi removida, uma vez que era desnecessária.

Comment: Muito obrigado! É exatamente isso, obrigado também pela edição!